# Python send simple mail

Tags: python, function, sendmail

Im trying to write a simple script which has to send a simple email in some cases.
I have the following script which works well if im using just only this script.

```
import smtplib

mail_user = '123@123.com'
mail_password = 'password'

sent_from = mail_user
to = ['reciever@address.com']
subject = 'My subject'
body = 'Hello mail.'

email_text = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('mail.123.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(mail_user, mail_password)
    server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    server.close()

    print 'Email sent!'
except:
    print 'Something went wrong...'
```

The problem is when im trying to put this code into a def and call from outside the e-mail is missing headers, i mean the email is arriving without sender and without subject. Sender empty and subject empty, but i have only the body.
I also can not get the mail when im sending to another domain, but i think this is because the another domain is rejecting the mail without headers, when using only the script the mail arrives also to other domains.

```
import smtplib

def sendMail():

  mail_user = '123@123.com'
  mail_password = 'password'

  sent_from = mail_user
  to = ['reciever@address.com']
  subject = 'My subject'
  body = 'Hello mail.'

  email_text = """\
  From: %s
  To: %s
  Subject: %s

  %s
  """ % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

  try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('mail.123.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(mail_user, mail_password)
    server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    server.close()

    print 'Email sent!'
  except:
    print 'Something went wrong...'

sendMail();
```

What is the diffenerece when i put this code into a def? Why this happening? What im doing wrong?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function version, your email headers have become **indented**

```
email_text = """\
  From: %s
  To: %s
  Subject: %s

  %s
  ...
```

In this string, the `To:` and `Subject:` are now indented.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sendMail():
```

call it with:

```
sendMail()
```

not SendMail()

Comment: The problem is not that, i made a mistake only here with capital letters, i have corrected in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to see the output of your console to see where it reports the error?

Comment: Both code are identical but may be difference in  Tab  or Space  indentation.   Check indentation (spaces)  not (tab)